# How to authorize my app with Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

I know I have seen apps that log me in using Facebook but never present me with an authorization screen.  I can not, for the life of me, figure out how to do this with Windows Phone 7.  The best I have been able to get is using the Facebook for C# SDK to get the authorization screen in a WebView.  This looks hideous and the page does not even appear to be mobile ready.

I have searched high and low for an answer and have found nothing. Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction to getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I also saw this kind of apps (e.g. Spotify prompts you to enter your Facebook account credentials rather than using the normal authorization flow). My best guess is that they either some kind of premium partners and have access to some private APIs or they use custom authorization flows (e.g. when you authorize an app on a website, the system saves authorization key in the database. The same app id/secret is then used in Windows Phone app and all you need to do is to type in your email/username in order for the system to locate authorization key that was saved earlier).

I also don't like the approach of displaying Facebook login/auth using WebBrowser control (mostly because of UI inconsistency) but I'd say that this is still the way to go in most cases (because this is the official and recommended way of authorizing the app and all other approaches seem hacky for me and also have their disadvantages).

You will want to be using the "server-side authentication" approach. The following document describes how it works: [Server-side authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) (read also [OAuth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) documentation for how to configure the authentication dialog). You can change the way the UI looks by passing a `display` parameter (either to `touch` or `wap`).

Please note that `display=touch` is currently broken in Windows Phone - Facebook always falls back to `wap` which is deprecated and will be removed as per [July 2012 update](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) (corresponding case: [Facebook API can't be used with Windows Phone apps](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/355102764525510)). It's also among known issues on Facebook C# SDK project page: [Facebook C# SDK - Known issues](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/known-issues).

Hope this clarifies things a bit.